# Make a button appear in a Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following Shiny Application:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

UI <- fluidPage(
     actionButton("get_tweets", "Fetch tweets"),
     numericInput("tweet_amount", "Set the amount of Tweets", 10, min = 10, max = 1000),
     selectInput("tweet_name", "Select the tweeter", selected = NULL, choices = c("@RealDonaldTrump")),

     #Set hidden buttons
     hidden(
       div(id="status_update",
           verbatimTextOutput("status")
           )
     ),
     hidden(
       div(id="tweet_fetcher",
        verbatimTextOutput("status2")
       )
     )
)

Server <- function(input, output){

  list = c(1,2,3)
  get_connected <- reactive({
    for(i in 1:length(list)){
      Sys.sleep(2)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$get_tweets, {
    get_connected()
    toggle("status_update")
    output$status <- renderText({"You're now connected to the API"})
    toggle("tweet_fetcher")
    output$status2 <- renderText("Test")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

Thing is that now I works. However, ideally I would like to make sure a button appears. Therefore I want to change:

```
output$status2 <- renderText("Test")
```

and this

```
verbatimTextOutput("status2") #actionButton("status2", "a_button")
```

This does not work. Any tips on what I should use if I want JS to let a button appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly you want to interchange
`verbatimTextOutput("status2")` with `actionButton("status2", "a_button")`.

Then you should use `renderUI()`:

- Server side: `output$status2 <- renderUI(actionButton("status2",
  "a_button"))`
- UI side: `uiOutput("status2")`

Full app would read:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

UI <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("get_tweets", "Fetch tweets"),
  numericInput("tweet_amount", "Set the amount of Tweets", 10, min = 10, max = 1000),
  selectInput("tweet_name", "Select the tweeter", selected = NULL, choices = c("@RealDonaldTrump")),

  #Set hidden buttons
  hidden(
    div(id="status_update",
        verbatimTextOutput("status")
    )
  ),
  hidden(
    div(id="tweet_fetcher",
        uiOutput("status2")
    )
  )
)

Server <- function(input, output){

  list = c(1,2,3)
  get_connected <- reactive({
    for(i in 1:length(list)){
      Sys.sleep(2)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$get_tweets, {
    get_connected()
    toggle("status_update")
    output$status <- renderText({"You're now connected to the API"})
    toggle("tweet_fetcher")
    output$status2 <- renderUI(actionButton("status2", "a_button"))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```